# best way to store a list of objects throw several pages in wp7 development

Tags: list, windows-phone-7

i have e.g. a class like:

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

now i have to access a list of type `List<Person>` in several pages. so i implemented a singleton class which stores this informations.
is there a better solution, or does i make it right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As with most questions of this type, it depends on the app.

A common practice for objects/lists which are required by multiple pages it to have an application level view model and reference this from each page.